# Non-managed referenced code strangely, "magically" changes its state for no reason when wrapped in managed

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a very strange problem:

My unmanaged third-party library has a class, let's call it `Foo` which has a method `bar()` which returns an object of type `Bar`, like:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = foo -> bar();
```

Now, this `Bar` has a method which is supposed to initially return `true` when it is obtained via the above means. In unmanaged code, this works as desired:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = foo -> bar(); // yes, bar() returns the object, not a pointer
bool b = bar.shouldBeTrue(); // b is true
```

Now, I wrote a managed wrapper for `Foo` and `Bar` which is very simple:

Managed.h:

```
namespace Managed {

    public ref class ManagedBar {
    private:
        ThirdParty::Bar* _delegate;

    public:
        ManagedBar(ThirdParty::Bar* delegate);

        ~ManagedBar();

        bool shouldBeTrue();
    };

    public ref class ManagedFoo {
    private:
        ThirdParty::Foo* _delegate;

    public:
        ManagedFoo();

        ~ManagedFoo();

        ManagedBar^ bar();
    };
}
```

ManagedBar.cpp (includes stripped):

```
namespace Managed {

    ManagedBar::ManagedBar(ThirdParty::Bar* delegate) {
        _delegate = delegate;
    }

    ManagedBar::~ManagedBar() {
        delete _delegate;
    }

    bool ManagedBar::shouldBeTrue() {
        return _delegate -> shouldBeTrue();
    }
}
```

ManagedFoo.cpp:

```
namespace Managed {

    ManagedFoo::ManagedFoo() {
        _delegate = new ThirdParty::Foo();
    }

    ManagedFoo::~ManagedFoo() {
        delete _delegate;
    }

    ManagedBar^ ManagedFoo:bar() {
        ThirdParty::Bar tpb = delegate -> bar();
        //for test/debugging:
        bool b = tpb.shouldBeTrue(); // b is true
        return gcnew ManagedBar(&tpb);
    }
}
```

Now, when I call this the following in VB.NET (in a Unit test):

```
Imports Managed

<TestClass()>
Public Class MyTest

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub TestBarReturnsTrue()
        Dim f as ManagedFoo = New ManagedFoo()
        Dim b as ManagedBar = f.bar()
        Assert.IsTrue(b.shouldBeTrue())
    End Sub

End Class
```

But the assert now fails because it is false. When I step into my `ManagedBar`, the `_delegate -> shouldBeTrue()` is called without any errors. This behaviour is very strange. Could it be that I did something wrong with my wrapping, or do I have to ask the supplier of the third-party DLL for advice?

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the behavior with dummy implementation of Bar (if you create your own Foo and Bar, with implementation bool Bar::shouldBeTrue() const { return true;}, and put them into dll to be called from your wrapper)?

Comment: I would need to create an unmanaged Win32 DLL for this, I suppose?

Comment: You are storing a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).  The ThirdParty::Bar destructor runs when ManagedFoo:bar() completes.  Dereferencing the pointer produces undefined behavior.  You have to keep the returned Bar object alive by storing it.

Comment: Is there a way to store the Bar object or do I have to implement something like a registry for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
    ManagedBar^ ManagedFoo:bar() {
    ThirdParty::Bar tpb = delegate -> bar();
    //for test/debugging:
    bool b = tpb.shouldBeTrue(); // b is true
    return gcnew ManagedBar(&tpb);
}
```

tpb is destroyed after the function call. You should allocate tpb on the heap(you will need to manually free it), save it somewhere(as member) or pass it by value to the ManagedBar.

Hope that will help you.